# Use Linq to construct distinct, ordered of objects based on properties

Tags: c#, linq

```
class Foo()
{
    public Bar [] bars;
}

class Bar ()
{
    public string name;
    public int id;
}
```

I have an `IEnumerable<Foo>` and I want to construct an `IEnumerable<Bar>` which contains which contains every unique bar (and ordered by ID...but I can handle that part on my own).

I feel that this is the type of task that LINQ is made for..but I can't seem to figure out how to make it happen.

As an example, if I had:

```
foo[0] => bars { { name = "one", id = 1 }, { name = "two", id = 2 }, { name = "three", id = 3 },
foo[1] => bars { { name = "four", id = 4 }, { name = "four", id = 4 }
```

I would want my linq statement to return:

```
{ name = "one", id = 1 }, { name = "two", id = 2 }, { name = "three", id = 3 }, { name = "four", id = 4 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `Bar` class overrode `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, it would be very simple:

```
var values = foo.SelectMany(f => f.bars)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(b => b.id);
```

Without that equality implementation, you'll need to create your own `IEqualityComparer<Foo>` to pass into the `Distinct` method.

If you only need to care about the `id` to make them distinct, you could use `DistinctBy` from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) to make your life simpler:

```
var values = foo.SelectMany(f => f.bars)
                .DistinctBy(b => b.id)
                .OrderBy(b => b.id);
```

Or you could use an anonymous type as a quick hack to get an equality comparer across both values, still with MoreLINQ:

```
var values = foo.SelectMany(f => f.bars)
                .DistinctBy(b => new { b.id, b.name })
                .OrderBy(b => b.id);
```

It would almost certainly be better to implement equality in `Bar` though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Foos.SelectMany(foo => foo.bars).OrderBy(bar => bar.id).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

use `SelectMany()` or `Concat()` to combine the children into one and `Distinct()` to make them unique.